# Reference request: Is differentiation with respect to odds "a thing"?

Tags: pr.probability

This is a reference request. I am wondering whether differentiating with respect to odds is either a standard thing or a thing with a history.

Over on math.stackexchange.com someone asked how to prove an identity on binomial coefficients, and posted answers relied on either algebra or combinatorics or probability. Mine was that last kind, done by regarding a variable as odds. So I [posted another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2407373/differentiating-with-respect-to-odds) that has $32$ views in $5$ days but neither comments nor answers.

The relation between probability and odds is this:
\begin{align}
\omega & = \text{odds} = \frac{\text{probability}}{\text{complementary probability}} = \frac p {1-p} \in [0,\infty], \\[12pt]
p & = \text{probability} = \frac \omega {1+\omega} \in [0,1].
\end{align}

It seems that experts on special functions use the Pochhammer symbol $(a)_b$ for the *rising* factorial, and combinatorials use it to refer to the *falling* factorial. I will follow the latter convention:
$$
(a)_b = \underbrace{a(a-1)(a-2)(a-3) \cdots (a-b+1)}_{\displaystyle\text{number of factors} = b}.
$$
Suppose $X\sim\operatorname{Binomial}(n,p).$ It is routine to show that the factorial moments of $X$ are $\operatorname{E}((X)_m) = (n)_m p^m.$ Here we show that by differentiating with respect to $\omega.$

$$
\frac{d^m}{d\omega^m}(\omega+1)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k \frac{d^m}{d\omega^m} \omega^k
$$
$$
(n)_m (\omega+1)^{n-m} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k (k)_m \omega^{k-m}
$$
Dividing both sides by $(\omega+1)^n$ we have the $m$th factorial moment
$$
(n)_m \left( \frac \omega {\omega+1} \right)^m = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k (k)_m \left( \frac \omega {\omega+1}\right)^k \left( \frac 1 {\omega+1} \right) ^{n-k}
$$
$$
(n)_m p^m = \operatorname{E}((X)_m).
$$

So: Is differentiating with respect to odds "a thing"?

Comment: After posting this I felt compelled to search for the following, which I found immediately. I actually considered while posting above putting quotes around "Is" as well as "a thing" since it's obviously become a phrasal verb in recent popular usage. And one sees here that the poster clearly recognized that. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144171/phrasal-verb-be-a-thing

Comment: The odds are closely related to the natural parameter for the binomial distributions with fixed $n$ as an exponential family, and (partial) differentiation with respect to a natural parameter is mentioned in the section on differential identities for cumulants in the Wikipedia page on exponential families. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family